# read from mysql database,why chinese character can read by this

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8

Mysql is default set,all character_encoding is 'latin1',I have rightly store the chinese content.My programe is UTF-8 encode.But when i read from  mysql,I only succeed read chinese content through as follow :

```
 byte[]bb = rs.getBytes("description"); //rs is the ResultSet
 String result = new String(bb));
```

where result is the right content.
The question is why rs.getString(),or new String("content".getbyte(""),"utf-8")can't resolve his question.

Comment: How about the page encoding? Your IDE should have the option to save as UTF-8. Not just the MySQL output...

Comment: I am sure page encoding is right.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Can we get some screenshot of the output?

Comment: IDE is eclipse,I have set file save as UTF-8.connect sql URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8. and before sql operation ,I have set names 'latin1',I store the chinese content rightly,but read incorrect except use above method.